# Onchange didn't show or hide Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a problem with my Script, please take a look.

My Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#datetimepicker_mask2").change(function() 
    { 
    var tanggalnya = $("#datetimepicker_mask2").val();
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "http://localhost:84/helpdesk2/forgot_password/check_date/"+tanggalnya,
        success: function(msgtgl){ 
        if(msgtgl === 'benar' ){
            console.log(msgtgl);
            $('#form_email').show();
            }
        else
            {                   
            console.log(msgtgl);
            $('#form_email').hide();;
            }
        }
    });
return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML

```
<div class="login-box-body">
    <div id="form_email">
      <form action="http://localhost:84/helpdesk2/forgot_password/check_date/" method="post">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" name="email" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="hasiltanggal"></div>
        </div>
```

my PHP

```
function check_date($tanggalnya)
    {
        extract(PopulateForm());
        $nipnya = $this->session->userdata('nip');
        $hasil = $this->db->query("SELECT BirthDate from Employee where Nip = '".$nipnya."'")->row();
         if(indo_date($hasil->BirthDate)==indo_date($tanggalnya))
            {
                echo "benar";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "salah";
            }
    }
```

note: `populateform()` is one of my helper that handle the input.

I can't show my `form_email`. I wonder why, because in `console.log(msgtgl)` i receive `benar`.  So, the `form_email` should be showed up, right?

Comment: Don't spam tags.. remove PHP tag

Comment: where is `datetimepicker_mask2` element in your `html` ?

Comment: use   if($.trim(msgtgl) == 'benar' ){ .. }

Comment: well. i cut my code. because it's to much. here is my full script via inspect element. http://pastebin.com/6L0PMc10

Comment: First check whether you are getting `success` or `error` getting executed in `ajax` because in both the places you have `console.log`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i've try it twice, the `true input` and the `false input`. The `console_log` showing the result that depend on the input

Comment: Just try executing `$('#form_email').show();` from console and see if it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar issues with comparing returned data - for some reason I had to apply trim() to it before comparing the value, try the following:

```
if(msgtgl.trim() === 'benar' ){...
```

or

```
 var test=msgtgl.trim();
if(test=== 'benar' ){...
```

Comment: I don't know why  either but it worked for me - but it took me ages to find it!!! many grey hairs later!! glad I could help :)